# NAT - FTPS (Error : Failed to retrieve directory list)

Tags: ssl, ftp, vsftpd, ftps

I have setup [ftp](/questions/tagged/ftp) server (Ubuntu 13.04 / Picuntu 4.4) using [vsftpd](/questions/tagged/vsftpd). The plain FTP works perfectly fine. In order to secure the connection, I added [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) encryption. The server accepts the login credentials, after the clients accept the certificate. However something goes wrong at the client's side after the **`LIST`** command.

**The FTP client log is here:**

`Status:    Resolving address of my_website.info
Status: Connecting to 93.123.456.789:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to My Website.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER ftpuser1
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (93,123,456,789,11,200).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`

--
I have searched alot on many forums about this problem, but no solution was found anywhere. After many desperate hit-n-trial attempts for many days, I am seeking some guidance here. 
The conection is passive, the server explicity specifies the external IP address to the client, as well as specifies the ports in a narrow range i.e. 3000-3030
**The VSFTPD configuration file is here** :

`listen=YES 
anonymous_enable=NO 
local_enable=YES 
chroot_local_user=YES 
chroot_list_enable=NO 
pam_service_name=ftp 
check_shell=NO 
ftpd_banner=Welcome to my website. 
userlist_enable=YES 
userlist_deny=NO 
max_clients=5 
max_per_ip=2 
pasv_enable=YES 
pasv_min_port=3000 
pasv_max_port=3030 
pasv_address=93.123.4xx.7xx # (external IP address of the server) 
pasv_addr_resolve=NO 
write_enable=NO 
ssl_enable=YES 
force_local_logins_ssl=YES 
force_local_data_ssl=YES 
ssl_tlsv1=YES 
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem 
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem`

I have set proper port forwarding in router, i.e. the port 21 as well as ports in the range 3000-3030 are forwarded to the server machine. Also whenever I try to connect to the server from any location, I can see that the port assigned by the server is in the range 3000-3030 (e.g. in the above message 11*256+200=3016!)

Comment: Have you considered sftp instead of ftps?  Both are secure, but sftp is much easier to get working through a firewall since only on port is used.

Comment: Could you make a packet capture (using tcpdump/wireshark) of the connection, preferable one at the client and another at the server side. And what kind of router do you run, some (like apples airport extreme) have bound an ftp-proxy on port 21 which does not work with encrypted connections.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : I tried to analyze the traffic, but coludn't find anything readable beyond:
`Response: 234 Proceed with negotiation.`
any `Response` or `Request` below this is in form of  `\026\003\000\000\...`

Comment: I am using Telekom's SpeedPort W723V router, and have configured:  

**1.** the server to establish encrypted connection (PASV) on port (min. 3000, max. 3030) and,    

**2.** the router to forward the ports in range 3000-3030 to the ftpserver machine, from the list of devices recognized by the router.

Comment: I don't know if this router tries to be as smart as the Airport Extreme router and have an internal ftp-proxy. Please try to setup your ftp-server and port-forwarding on a different port than 21 to see if it works then.